# Access outer class proper inside nested class companion object

Tags: kotlin

I have a companion object in inner `data class` and I want to access outer class property inside inner class companion object. Also, I want to make keep the inner class as data class .

```
 class Outer(val data: String) {

  private data class Inner() {

    companion object {
    val default = Type(data = outer.data) 
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: You need your class to be `inner` to access parent fields. Also you can't access the parent class in the `companion object` as that exists indipendently of the sorrounding class. Additionally you can't have a `data class` with no fields (why would you want that anyway?)

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't make sense, for reasons of multiplicity:

- `Inner` is a [nested class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html), not an [`inner class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html#inner-classes).  This means that its instances aren't associated with `Outer` class instances, and exist independently.
- There's always exactly one instance of `Inner`'s [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).

So that there could be zero or more `Inner` instances, and the companion object doesn't have a reference to any of them — and even if it did, that wouldn't have a reference to any `Outer` instances (if there are any).

So **how would the companion object know which `Outer` instance's property to access?**

Your code has other problems as well:

- As the compiler says: `Data class must have at least one primary constructor parameter`.  The point of a `data class` is to hold properties; its `equals()` and `hashCode()` and all the other automatically-generated methods depend on those properties.  So it wouldn't make sense for a data class to have no properties!
- You don't define `Type`.
- I'd recommend renaming the `Outer` property, as `data` is a keyword in Kotlin.  It's a ‘soft’ keyword, so it can still be used as an identifier; but it could cause odd problems.